# Installing different iconv in same RedHat box

Tags: linux, glibc, rhel, iconv

I have new version of `iconv` installed in RedHat 8 (production). How can I **downgrade without affecting existing** `iconv` (as well as existing `glibc`) ?

Currently I have this:

```
iconv 2.28
RedHat 8.5
```

Need to move to:

```
iconv 2.22
```

Same Linux box without effecting old version.
I am okay to use the command as `iconv_old` or `/home/smily/iconv`. It should work somehow, that's all!

It would be great, if you can provide the commands I should try. I searched for adding it to Yum, but couldn't get a solution.

There are rpm files of `glibc` but I am not sure how to install (multiple versions) and which one I should download.

OR

Is there a problem if I downgrade `glibc` by using RPM command? I am not sure what for it is used and how it will affect the production machine.

Comment: Glibc *is* your OS (together with the kernel) and cannot be changed to another version.

Comment: Okay, @KnudLarsen , What would be the other option for me? There seems to be a bug in 2.28 version of iconv.

Comment: 1. Report the bug to Redhat. .......... 2. Use the " `iconv`-old" from Fedora 23 ( if it works / doesn't conflict with current files) https://archives.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/fedora/linux/updates/23/x86_64/g/glibc-2.22-18.fc23.x86_64.rpm ........ `unPack_rpm.sh`  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1q3d9QqrRhEThYByPDgWEaoxHnqWFWqfE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I tried @KnudLarsen. But couldn't find `iconv` anywhere in the unpacked directory or anywhere in the machine. (I have a new linux box installed in my VM for trying out). Tried `find / -type f | grep iconv` nowhere other than existing one.  Existing /usr/bin/iconv --version not changed too. (fedora 23 does not have iconv in glibc ?)

Comment: `$ bash unPack_rpm.sh glibc-2.22-4.12.2.x86_64.rpm`, and you get `glibc-2.22-4.12.2.x86_64/usr/bin/iconv`